# View profiles with Instagram API

Tags: php, api, instagram

I have a small problem, I have to make a site for a friend (a site for his Models), she asks me for each profile of a model to display the photos of her Instagram.

Currently I arrive posted a profile (mine) that I get with my own "access_token", here is my code:

```
$access_token = "my_access_token";
$photo_count = 4;
$json_link = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?";
$json_link .= "access_token={$access_token}&count={$photo_count}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$obj = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json), true);
foreach ($obj['data'] as $post) {
    echo "
    <div class=''>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-4'>               
    <img src='{$post["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]}' alt='{$post["caption"]["text"]}' style='width: 25%''>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
```

Here I can not find a way for example to display the photos of a person, the only way that comes to mind is to ask each person their access_token that I will store in my database. In my opinion it's not a good solution but I do not know how to do it more easily.

EDIT: Like for exemple the instagram part on 
like for exemple the instagram part on [Exemple](http://www.womenmanagement.com/model/2762/karly-loyce/)

Comment: See [the api docs homepage](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) - the feature you are currently using is going to go away in about a year. It isn't worth developing code which depends on it.

Comment: @Quentin oh ok thank you very much, i just saw the new api docs and i dont think if i understand all. but i think i will have the same problem. now i use my access_token to return my instagram pictures.  but i dont know how to return the instagram pictures of differents Users.

Comment: I can't see anything in the docs which makes that possible. It looks like they are not offering that service to third parties.

Comment: Yes i don't know why, it's weird i know it's possible cause i have seen this on other sites but i cant do the same thing. I edited my question to see what i want to do.